# How to get back objects form list to their former positions after sorting the list?

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, collections

I have sorted my List and put sorted list in my table, now i want to unsort list but how to do that(i have JCheckBox to check when i want to sort my list and uncheck to unsort it)?

```
sort.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean n = sort.isSelected();
        if (n) {
            AutoListSort comparator = new AutoListSort();
            Collections.sort(Controller.getList(), comparator);
            refresh.refresh();
        }
    }

});
```

My sorting class:

```
public class AutoListSort implements Comparator<Auto> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Auto person1, Auto person2) {

        return person1.getGodiste().compareTo(person2.getGodiste());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any generic way to "unsort" a sorted list/collection. The easiest thing to do is probably to maintain two lists: The original (unsorted) list and the sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep the previous state (an unsorted list) and update it right before the sort operation is performed.
2. Create a field (e.g. `addedAt` - the date of addition to the list) to make a backup possible.

I would like to call your attention to the way you are dealing with the controller. You are changing its state rather than **providing the state you want to display**. The idea I suggest is to pass a sorted copy to the controller and to keep the original data in somewhere else (e.g. in a service).

The second thing, you should think over, is a place where a `Comparator` should be initialised. You don't necessarily need to create a `Comparator` **every time the event occurs**.

The third point relates the `AutoListSort`. Make sure that the arguments and the `Auto#getGodiste` calls don't return a `null`, otherwise, an NPE is likely to happen. BTW, I would use the statement

```
Comparator.comparing(Auto::getGodiste).compare(person1, person2);
```

which seems to be more expressive for me.